# In App SMS in iPhone SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios-simulator

Does any one know how to implement In App SMS functionality in iPhone SDK 4.0

Sandy

Comment: NDA cops commenting in 3, 2, 1...

Comment: If you sign up and download the SDK, you may find information about this. However everything in pre-release SDK's from Apple are under NDA, so nobody here are allowed to answer you with any specific knowledge concerning this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to not violate NDA, I direct you to read about [this class](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668), and ask about it in [Apple's Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/).